# Using clabel to add labels with a transparent background

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

For matplotlib.pyplot.clabel, is it possible to add labels to a contour plot without the white space behind the labels covering up any portion the contour lines?  When I try to add labels to a contour plot it tends to cover up part of the contour plot with white space.  Perhaps there is a way of making the background of the text transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `inline` argument

```
 plt.clabel(..., inline=False)
```

Comment: That's great.  Thank you.  Do you know if you can adjust the size of the white region that it normally created when inline = True?

Comment: From what I understand, `inline_spacing` should do exactly that. But I can't know why it fails in your case without [mcve].